# R{base} keep trailing zeros in scientific notation

Tags: r, numbers, format

I'm trying that every number of a list remains with the same format.
Does anybody know how to keep, in R, the trailing zeros in a number with scientific notation format?

Example:

```
x<-0.2195649
format(x, scientific = T,digits = 3)
#[1] "2.2e-01"
```

The desired result would be:

```
[1] "2.20e-01"
```

Comment: You may want to try the options command: options(digits=6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm almost certain that there is a duplicate of this question somewhere. In any case, the desired output can be obtained with `sprintf()`:

```
sprintf("%.2e", x)
#[1] "2.20e-01"
```

The `"%.2e"` format specifier indicates that the number `x` should be displayed with two digits after the decimal point in normalized scientific notation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if this is duplicated I can't find it, and this is the first response that comes up on google when you search `tell R not to remove trailing zeros when reporting in scientific notation`!